# Bitmap drawing with phaser is pixelated

Tags: phaser-framework, bitmapdata

I've been developing a paint app using Phaser. However the lines gets pixelated. Here is my [code](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OgRWMe):

```
for (var i = 1; i < points.length; i++) {
      paintBoard.ctx.beginPath();

      paintBoard.ctx.moveTo(points[i - 1].x, points[i - 1].y);

      paintBoard.ctx.lineTo(points[i].x, points[i].y);
      paintBoard.ctx.closePath();
      paintBoard.ctx.stroke();
}
```

Comment: So what would you like to achieve? Maybe that helps others to answer your question. As on your codepen I cannot see what's wrong with it.

Comment: Hi Fuzzzzel. I want it it not pixelated. I want it smooth. Hope anyone can help me improve the code.

Comment: Hmmm, mabe it's not your code. Could you add a Screenshot? When I try your codepen, I only see minimal pixels - bit this is, because a Screen has only oixels to display something. Maybe it has to do with something else.

Comment: @Fuzzzzel here is the link of the image. thanks http://i67.tinypic.com/34i1hr8.jpg

Comment: That's basically how it looks like here too. I don't think you can change anything as the grid is defined by pixels/your resolution. If you try cheap drawing apps lile paint on windows it's pretty much the same picture. Sorry I cannot help you with this.